# How to use associations in model validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

Having a **model1** with **belongs_to :model2** association. **model2** has an attribute called **duration** with an integer. **model1** has an attribute called **start_day**. In this model, I want to validate that **start_day** is less than or equal to **duration** of model2.

I added the following line to model1:

```
validates_numericality_of :start_day, :less_than_or_equal_to => :model2.duration
```

Rails fires a **NoMethodError (undefined method `duration' for :model2:Symbol)**

model2 has an attribute duration...

Any idea what I am missing? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`less_than_or_equal_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_numericality_of) option needs a numerical value, a symbol that names an instance method, or a Proc to be executed at validation time. You probably want the third option:

```
validates_numericality_of :start_day,
    :less_than_or_equal_to => Proc.new { |model1| model1.model2.duration }
```

Or if you have a method in model1 called `model2_duration` you could shorten it to this:

```
validates_numericality_of :start_day, :less_than_or_equal_to => :model2_duration
```